# Converting datetime sql server type to JSON python

Tags: python, json, sql-server

I developed an API to my sql server azure database,deployed  with azure functions.

I have Python code that is using request to call the API which is also in Python.

I have one issue that i am not able to resolve ,

Description of my objective :
I am getting 10K records from one table with the API and want to insert them into a new table , since the request is HTTPS i am converting the query result into json with json.dumps .

The problem:
In most of my database tables i have a field that is populated with sysdatetime() sql function.
When trying to preform the insert command(I am using executemany) i am getting:
'String data, right truncation: length 52 buffer 46'

Example:
I have 10K list of list the in each list i have item in the following format
'2020-04-15 05:02:10.023000'.
from the other hand:
'2020-04-14 00:00:00' is not throwing errors.

The solution i am looking:
To be able to convert to Json in my code(I prefer not to change the API code) with out need to iterate over all records one by one.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Nir

Comment: Can you please add some code and maybe some examples of the API dates you receive, and which is the format you need?

Comment: When i sending the rows to the API i am using: self.Data=json.dumps(Params,indent=4, sort_keys=False on the API side i am using Data=req.get_json()  on the example i wrote you can see the format getting from the DB and this is how it it in the API :2020-04-15 05:02:10.023000

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the problem correctly, I think that you have a problem with the length of the data. As you can see when you have:

> '2020-04-14 00:00:00'

You dont get any problem, but when changing to:

> '2020-04-15 05:02:10.023000'

An error appears because there are too many digits... The easiest way to solve this is by truncating the string. So, when you're passing the data to the new table, you should do something like this:

```
if "." in data:
    data=data[:(data.rfind(':'))+3]
    #do whatever with the data now
else:
    #do whatever with the data
```

Comment: Thanks, yes  , i know that this is the issue, but i want to avoid going over 10K records * number of items in each record

Comment: @NirElbaz I would then change the floating precission of your datas inside the application. I don't know, but probably you won't need miliseconds to appear.

Comment: Thanks, This is what i will do, i was trying to avoid it, but i think i dont have any other choise